# htaccess allow if does not contain string

Tags: apache-2.2, password, .htaccess

I'm trying to setup a .htaccess file which will allow users to bypass the password block if they come from a domain which does not start with preview. e.g. http://preview.example.com would trigger the password and http://example.com would not.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host preview(.*\.)? preview_site
AuthUserFile /Users/me/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Development Area"
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Allow from 127
deny from env=preview_site
Satisfy any
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where almost there, a couple of points:

Your regex though valid, also matches when preview in somewhere else in the URL (eg. test.preview.example.com). The following only matches if the URL starts with "preview."

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^preview\. preview_site
```

The order needs to change to "Allow,Deny", because you want mod_access to fail when both Deny and Allow statements match. After mod_access fails the mod_auth will be called because of the "Satify Any".

So this should provide the behavior you are looking for:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^preview\. preview_site
AuthUserFile /Users/me/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Development Area"
Require valid-user
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
Deny from env=preview_site
Satisfy Any
```